# Passing cmd line variables from a php file

Tags: php, c, command-line-arguments

Is this possible from a PHP file

```
$var1 = 1  
$var2 = 2  
$output = `./a.out $var1 $var2 `
```

or

```
$output = exec(./a.out $var1 $var2);
```

consider a.out to be the C program executable.

Where $var1 and $var2 are passed as command line arguements? If this is not possible, is there any other easier way of passing php variables as input to my C program executable?

Thanks!

Comment: its really easy to know whether its possible or not, you just gotta jot down those few lines into file and execute it. did you give it a shot?

Comment: I agree it is very experimental and doable.. The reason i posted it was to know subtleties involved while doing this and other alternatives available if any..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible.

Since you are asking for potential alternatives, you could consider passing the arguments as environment variables instead (which might be insignificantly easier to access in your C binary):

```
exec("VAR1='$var1' VAR2='$var2' ./a.out");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it would work. The syntax however is little different:

```
$output = exec("./a.out $var1 $var2");
```

Php would put the actual values into the string, so `a.out` would execute with arguments `1 2`.